# Hold a Socket.IO Connection throughout Application while it in running foreground or background

Tags: android, socket.io

I have made my one to one and group chat application using socket.io , everything is working fine , but If I am interacting with UI it establish the connection but after some time when I stop interacting with the application  then  the connect break and  user goes offline as I am not using any event for putting my user offline. Can anyone help me in this.

```
 public  SocketConnection() {
    {
        try {
            nSocket = IO.socket(Constants.NAME_SPACE);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}


public Socket getSocket(){
    return  nSocket;
}
```

this is where I am putting my user online.

```
 public class SplashActivity extends ActivityManagePermission {
    String permissionAsk[] = {PermissionUtils.Manifest_CAMERA
           , PermissionUtils.Manifest_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
          , PermissionUtils.Manifest_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
           };
     Context context = SplashActivity.this;
    private JSONObject mJson;
    SessionManagement session;
private Socket mSocket;
int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 2000;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    session = new SessionManagement(context);

    /**
     * Creating the socket connection.
     */
    SocketConnection obj = new SocketConnection();
    try {
        mSocket = obj.getSocket();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            askCompactPermissions(permissionAsk, new PermissionResult() {
                @Override
                public void permissionGranted() {
                    if(session.isSignedIn()) {
                        mJson = new JSONObject(); //creating json object
                        Object type = "M";
                        Object ID_USER = session.getUserDetails().get(SessionManagement.USER_ID);
                        try {
                            mJson.put("userId", ID_USER);
                            mJson.put("connection_type",type);
                        }catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        mSocket.emit(Constants.event_new_user_online,mJson.toString());
                        mSocket.connect();
                        Intent i = new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void permissionDenied() {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void permissionForeverDenied() {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                            "Please allow the permissions"
                            ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    startActivity(new Intent(context,SplashActivity.class));
                }
            });

        }

    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
}
```

}

Comment: Since there are Background restrictions introduced in Android you can not perform any Continuous background task . The only way to do this is a Foreground  Service(Which is not recommended at all for a Chat application). You an Rely of `Jobs` and FCM messages .

Comment: There is no other way to do that my whole application is working fine i don't want to switch to FCM messages.

Comment: So In case If socket connection is losing If application is inactive, you can make a Timer which checks for the socket connection periodically and establish connection if socket is not connected. Otherwise, FCM is an alternate.

Comment: As of the best practices its not recommended you should use notifications and write your logic accordingly to update the UI when app comes in foreground.

Though you can add patch like create a foreground service to keep it alive but again you will not be able to do UI operations that you will have manage when app comes to foreground.

Also make sure to close the connection when service is destroyed.

Comment: I am afraid that's the way it is .. Just take example of any other Chat Application they all are doing the same. App killed -> Person goes offline ...then the push notifications comes to party ..

Comment: @ADM that's the prestigious way for this issue.

Comment: okey I will try to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Socket IO options](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#new-Manager-url-options).

```
IO.Options options = IO.Options()

options.setTimeout(60000L) // 60 seconds
options.setReconnection(true)
```

and then use it like this while making a connection.

```
nSocket = IO.socket(Constants.NAME_SPACE, options);
```